# Pass datetime parameter from pipeline to dataflow source stored procedure azure data factory

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I faced with the issue when I tried to pass datetime parameter from pipeline to dataflow stored procedure.
I've using stored procedure for getting full or incremental dataset.
Pipeline looks like this
[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4O5v.png)
In lookup I am getting 'n/a' or last load date. to determine do I need full or incremental load.
After that I passed it to dataflow with the expressions:

LoadStartDate `activity('GetLastLoadData').output.value[0].LastLoadedDate`
LoadEndDate `if(equals(activity('GetLastLoadData').output.value[0].LastLoadedDate, 'n/a'), '' ,pipeline().TriggerTime)`

[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is3UK.png)

Output seems good and as far as I can see parameters of dataflow was set with datetime strings:

```
Input
{
    "dataflow": {
        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
        "type": "DataFlowReference",
        "parameters": {
            "LoadStartDate": "'2021-01-16 14:15:36.697'",
            "LoadEndDate": "'2021-03-25T18:08:48.7558444Z'"
        },
```

Stored procedure has two parameters defined as string. I am doing validation

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Export]
@LoadStartDate VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
@LoadEndDate VARCHAR(30) = NULL

AS 

DECLARE @error VARCHAR(200) = NULL

IF (@LoadStartDate IS NULL AND @LoadEndDate IS NOT NULL) OR
   (@LoadStartDate IS NOT NULL AND @LoadEndDate IS NULL)
   SELECT @error = 'Parameters @LoadStartDate and @LoadEndDate should be specified.'

IF @LoadStartDate IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CAST(@LoadStartDate AS DATETIME2(3)) IS NULL 
SELECT @error = 'Parameter @LoadStartDate is not a date.'
IF @LoadEndDate IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CAST(@LoadEndDate AS DATETIME2(3)) IS NULL 
SELECT @error = ' Parameter @LoadEndDate is not a date.'
```

In management studio procedure works well but not in adf...

ADF dataflow has two parameters defined as a string
[ADF parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khj9e.png)

The setting of a source look like this:
[source settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2n5v.png)

When I deteled input parameters everything works well( as a full load), but when I've tried to specify parameters it failed.

```
Error details
Error code
DFExecutorUserError
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: Incorrect syntax near '-'.","Details":"Incorrect syntax near '-'."}
Source
Pipeline
LoadDataSetCompany_copy1
Data flow
dataflow1
Monitor
Data flow activity
LoadDataSet
```

I've also tried to select the expression checkbox, during passing parameter to dataflow but it did not help.

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong?

Appreciated the answers.

Comment: Can you check the source data preview?

Comment: yes, but only in case if I do not specify input parameters for stored procedure

Comment: Hi @edKud, do you use other data flow active? Can you try lookup + copy active to build your pipeline?

Comment: @LeonYue thank you it seems that this is only working case

Comment: Yes, you're welcome. may I post it as answer?

Comment: you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: ADF Engineering team is looking into it. Maybe a bug in the way we are passing parameters to sprocs in data flows.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT thank you. If some help required from my side to reproduce it - I can share pipeline and dataflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per my experience, you may don't need to use Data Flow to build your pipeline.  The stored procedure is new to Data Flow and may still have some issues.

Please try Lookup active + Copy active to build the pipeline, it should works well.

HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to. Because I need to perform a lot of transformation and validation with the dataset. But as per your recommendation, I can stage data and use use staged dataset as a source

Answer (score 1):

I had a discussion with microsoft support and with their help I finally resolve the issue.

Expression to pass parameter in dataflow should looks like "'{$LoadStartDate}'". After passing parameters such way parsing error diaspeared.

Also in my stored proc I've used t-sql throw after validation of parameters if they contain not appropriate values. THROW should be avoided and when I remove it dataflow started working as expected.

Hopefully this information will save time for somebody.